# Python can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)

def epoch_seconds(date):
    """Returns the number of seconds from the epoch to date."""
    print(epoch)
    td = date - epoch
    return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)
```

When I take a date directly from my model I get the following error:

> print(epoch_seconds(self.modified))

**can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**

So I checked the format of both `self.modified` and `epoch`

```
self.modified = 2015-08-13 16:29:37.601681+00:00
epoch = 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

I think I understand the error and need these to be in the same format however, I have no idea what `.601681+00:00` is and how to do this. Could some help to explain the what is after the `.` and how to get these to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a datetime object you can get the seconds from the epoch from it directly:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
print int(d.strftime("%s"))
```

In your question, `.601681` is extra resolution in the time, in microseconds,
and  `+00:00` is the offset in hours:minutes from UTC (previously GMT).

Comment: This solution doesn't  works in python 3. In Python 3.3+ you can use timestamp() instead:

Answer (score 8):

After the dot, there's the timezone information, which, for this situation, I don't believe you need.  Just go ahead and get rid of that timezone info this way:

```
date = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
```